# How to install Pytorch with CUDA support using conda?

Tags: pytorch, conda

I downloaded cuda and pytorch using conda:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

`conda list`

```
python                    3.11.0               h7a1cb2a_2    anaconda
pytorch                   2.0.1              py3.11_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h7e8668a_5    pytorch
torchaudio                2.0.2                 py311_cpu    pytorch
torchvision               0.15.2                py311_cpu    pytorch
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Output:

```
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Just noting, I had exactly this situation and what fixed it for me was:

conda uninstall pytorch

then run your same cuda based install command again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34704181)

Answer (score 1):

It can be quite a few reasons for this behaviour. I will list a few and the information needed to confirm those.

- Driver is not installed or is older.

  - Share the output of nvidi-smi command to verify this.
- Old hardware with cuda compute capability lower than minimum requirement for pytorch

  - Share the output of nvidi-smi command to verify this.
- You are using a different python interpretor than the one from your conda environment.

  - print torch.**file** to know where torch is loading from.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you're building the conda environment on a machine which has an older nvidia driver not supported by this version of CUDA (11.8). The conda installer is too smart for it's own good and will automatically give you the cpu version of pytorch **even though** you're also installing pytorch-cuda. I've tested this myself by building the environment on different machines with different GPU's and Nvidia drivers installed. It's unlikely to be the python version (as included in the previous answer) as a correct version of python will be installed in the environment when you build it.